# JavaFX HTMLEditor: how to set line-height?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Does Anybody know how to change line height in `HTMLEditor`?

It looks like default is 200% and I need 100%.

I want the same effect: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the `line-height` in a `HTMLEditor`.

On abstract way is: **Specify the line-height in HTML based CSS (not JavaFX CSS) -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731041/line-spacing-htmleditor-javafx)**

The only way to make the `HTMLEditor` look like this:

[image]

is to remove all `manuall brakes`. The `HTMLEditor` is wraping the text himselfe. Manuall `Brakes` will look every time like this:

[image]

Hope this helps you :)